# Sidekiq Procfile Queue Exclusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

Below is an example set up of a Procfile using Sidekiq:

```
web: bundle exec thin start -p $PORT
worker: bundle exec sidekiq
```

To define specific queues for a worker, the `-q` flag is used to do the inclusion.

```
web: bundle exec thin start -p $PORT
worker: bundle exec sidekiq -q low_priority
```

My question: is there a way to do an exclusion of a queue for a worker instead?

My use case is the following:

- General worker that handles all the the queues except one (lets call it `resource_intensive`)
- A specialized worker that has more resources behind it to handle the `resource_intensive` queue only.

The set-up using only the inclusion `-q` flag would be something like the below, where `low_priority`, `high_priority`, `default`, and `resource_intensive` are the queues which exist:

```
web: bundle exec thin start -p $PORT
worker: bundle exec sidekiq -q high_priority -q default -q low_priority
resource_intensive_worker: bundle exec sidekiq -q resource_intensive
```

A less error prone set-up would just exclude the `resource_intensive` queue from `worker`. Does a queue exclusion flag exist?